# How to setup fcm-django properly

Tags: django

I new to push notification, so I'm sorry for this stupid questions and also I'm unclear about some the terminology used in this package. Here I've some question.

-Is the server key and fcm api key is same?

-do i need to add some extrnal js script ko make this package work properly. if can you please share some guide or pdf or some link which help me to integrate this.

-Do i need to add FCM Device manually? Please make me clear about fcm device.

-After setup this project, i didn't get any notification to enable or disable push notifications.

Here is my setup

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
.......
    "fcm_django",
]
FCM_DJANGO_SETTINGS = {
        "FCM_SERVER_KEY": "AAAA......:................................................MGC22WxjWHHcKOo"
}

Note: FCM_SERVER_KEY is server key instead of web api key
```

If i need to add FCM Device how can i add FCM Devices properly, because i didn't know, from where and how to garb all the value for model FCM Device model fields.

Comment: I will suggest you to use https://github.com/jazzband/django-push-notifications. If requirement arises, it supports iphone as well as windows push notifications as well

Comment: my requirements is only web, so think fcm_django is fine, I tried to setup `django-push-notifications`,  same problem in django-push-notifications